# Como criar novos diretórios no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou criando um aplicativo no Android Studio que possui muitas telas e muitos arquivos de `layout.xml`. Queria organizar-los em sub-pastas, é possível?

Tentei editar o `Gradle Script`, porem apareceram muitas mensagens de erro.

Comment: Olá! Este é o Stackoverflow em português! Por favor edite sua pergunta! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode configurar suas pasta com a seguinte configuração no Gradle.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res2', 'src/main/res_qq_coisa']
    }
}
```